# Running a Javascript Sort Through Apple Automator

Tags: javascript, sorting, automator

I am trying to use the following code in Apple Automator

```
var lnRange = getSelectedLineRange();
var ln = getTextInRange(lnRange[0],lnRange[1]);

var lines = ln.split('\n').sort(function(a, b)
{
  var parsedA = a.replace(/\*\s(<s>)?(The )?/, "* ");
  var parsedB = b.replace(/\*\s(<s>)?(The )?/, "* ");

  return parsedA.localeCompare(parsedB);
});
setTextInRange(lnRange[0],lnRange[1],lines.join('\n'));
```

I know the code is sound and achieves the results I need it to (Running it in Drafts on the iPhone produces exactly the results I require, namely sorting a markdown list while ignoring the use of `<s>` and/or "The "at the start of a line. The * needs to stay in so the list holds up).

Transferring it from the iPhone into Automator is where things fall apart, as Automator can't find the variable getSelectedLineRange. I'm guessing this is a conflict between how Automator handles the text input and how the script wants to take and process it, but I'm at an impasse as to how to resolve it.

For the sake of example (in the event of my entire approach being wrong) I'd like this list, in any text field I can throw at it

```
* Armadillo
* The aardvark
* <s>Rhino</s>
* <s>The Zebra</s>
* The Giraffe
* Hedgehog
```

when selected, to go through the script, running as a service, and come out like this

```
* The aardvark
* Armadillo
* The Giraffe
* Hedgehog
* <s>Rhino</s>
* <s>The Zebra</s>
```

I'm certainly not married to a javascript solution, but it's the starting point I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "**Run JavaScript**" action in **Automator** need the `run(input, parameters)` function.

**input** is an array that contains one item (the text).

```
function run(input, parameters) {
   var lines = input[0].split('\n').sort(function(a, b)
   {
      var parsedA = a.replace(/\*\s(<s>)?(The )?/, "* ");
      var parsedB = b.replace(/\*\s(<s>)?(The )?/, "* ");
      return parsedA.localeCompare(parsedB);
   });
   return lines.join('\n');
}
```

Comment: is there a way to "inspect" what exactly is inside input and parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar enough with JavaScript to help with that, but this AppleScript should work inside of a **Run AppleScript** Action:

```
on run {input}

    set rawParagraphs to every paragraph of (input as text)

    set recordsForSorting to {}

    repeat with eachPara in rawParagraphs
        if (eachPara as text)'s length > 0 then
            set end of recordsForSorting to my CheckText(eachPara as text)
        end if
    end repeat

    set sortedRecords to my bubblesort(recordsForSorting)

    set sortedText to ""
    repeat with eachRecord in sortedRecords
        set sortedText to sortedText & (eachRecord's ActualWord) & return
    end repeat

    return sortedText
end run

to CheckText(txt)
    if txt contains "<s>" then
        set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 4 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}
    else if txt contains "the" then
        set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 5 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}
    else
        set sortRecord to {SortWord:txt, ActualWord:txt}
    end if
    return sortRecord
end CheckText

-------------------------
on bubblesort(array)
    repeat with i from length of array to 2 by -1 --> go backwards
        repeat with j from 1 to i - 1 --> go forwards
            tell array
                if (item j)'s SortWord > (item (j + 1))'s SortWord then
                    set {item j, item (j + 1)} to {item (j + 1), item j} -- swap
                end if
            end tell
        end repeat
    end repeat
    return array
end bubblesort
```

The script creates a record for each paragraph which contains the actual text, and the same text with "the" or "" removed.  It then uses a bubble sort on the target term, returning a string of the actual text times in sorted order.

I did not make any provision for the asterisk; I was not sure from your post if that was part of the original issue, or a stack overflow formatting thing.

I did not test it as a Service, but it worked in Automator with standard input text and subsequent output to a text file.

Good luck,

Comment: The main problem with my **CheckText** handler is that if a line contains <s>, then it assumes that the line BEGINS with <s>, and then only evaluates the first character that comes after the first four characters.  If there is a space, tab, or anything else between the <s> and the first character of the sorting target, or, if there is anything preceding the <s>, it will fail.  In order for the handler to to be perfect every time, it must be either written to anticipate ANY <s> usage, or coded in such a way to locate the target regardless of surrounding junk.  Either is time-consuming.

Comment: I think I've solved the issue, for my needs at least, which hopefully sidesteps the above. Thank you for the original code to work from, I'd still be stuck trying to find a workaround to make the javascript work without it.

Comment: You are welcome.  AppleScript is kind of clunky for serious text manipulation and sorting, but in the latest OS, it works pretty darn fast once your code is functional.

Answer (score 0):

Working from the answer @Craig gave I've found the following script deals with my problem, and will hopefully help others.

```
on run {input}

set rawParagraphs to every paragraph of (input as text)

set recordsForSorting to {}

repeat with eachPara in rawParagraphs
    if (eachPara as text)'s length > 0 then
        set end of recordsForSorting to my CheckText(eachPara as text)
    end if
end repeat

set sortedRecords to my bubblesort(recordsForSorting)

set sortedText to ""
repeat with eachRecord in sortedRecords
    set sortedText to sortedText & (eachRecord's ActualWord) & return
end repeat

return sortedText
end run

to CheckText(txt)

if txt starts with "    * <s>The " then
    set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 11 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}

else if txt starts with "   * The " then
    set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 8 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}

else if txt starts with "   * <s>" then
    set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 7 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}

else if txt starts with "   * " then
    set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 4 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}

else if txt starts with "* <s> The " then
    set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 11 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}

else if txt starts with "* The " then
    set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 7 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}

else if txt starts with "* <s>" then
    set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 6 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}

else if txt starts with "* " then
    set sortRecord to {SortWord:((characters 3 thru -1 of txt) as text), ActualWord:txt}

else
    set sortRecord to {SortWord:txt, ActualWord:txt}
end if
return sortRecord
end CheckText

-------------------------
on bubblesort(array)
repeat with i from length of array to 2 by -1 --> go backwards
    repeat with j from 1 to i - 1 --> go forwards
        tell array
            if (item j)'s SortWord > (item (j + 1))'s SortWord then
                set {item j, item (j + 1)} to {item (j + 1), item j} -- swap
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end repeat
return array
end bubblesort`
```

I suspect there are some horrible errors I am solely to blame for lurking in there, but it seems to work.